# Authenticated remote IRI API calls. Fullnode startup flags and config

Tags: security, iri-node, iri-legacy-api

I want to enable API calls to my full node from an host besides localhost. The question is what startup flags or equivalent entries in an *.ini config file* do I need to make authenticated API calls?

From my experience these configurations are required:

```
API_HOST = 0.0.0.0
IRI_OPTIONS = "--remote"
REMOTE_AUTH = user:pw
```

(*user* is a username and *pw* a password.)

With this setup I need to provide a flag *--user usr:pw* if  I use curl. Example call:

```
curl --user usr:pw http://public-fullnodenode-ip:port -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'X-IOTA-API-Version: 1' -d '{"command": "getNeighbors"}'
```

The auth info *--user usr:pw* matches with the entry in my full node config .ini *REMOTE_AUTH = user:pw*.

This works but is probably not the correct way. Because following the startup flag [documentation](https://iotasupport.com/startup-flags.shtml) it should be a ***username:hashedpassword*** combination. Not a *username:password* combination:

> --remote-auth
>
> Require authentication password for accessing remotely. Requires a correct username:hashedpassword combination. Example input:
> --remote-auth iotatoken:LL9EZFNCHZCMLJLVUBCKJSWKFEXNYRHHMYS9XQLUZRDEKUUDOCMBMRBWJEMEDDXSDPHIGQULENCRVEYMO

So how is it done the correct way?

What hash algorithm should be used? And in the curl call behind *--user* is still a password (not the hash) provided?

The API call with curl is not transport encrypted right? Is it insecure to use the *--user* flag?

Answer (score 2):

1. IRI API currently uses HTTP Basic Authentication which transports username and password in an unencrypted form. I believe the documentation is implicitly suggesting that you shouldn't use your regular user account password but rather some arbitrary large random string which can be easily generated by hashing some text or your regular password (which I would advise against if not using some random prefix - salt). You have to specify the same string for curl password as in your *iri.ini* or command line argument to *--remote-auth*.
2. IRI API is exposed via plain HTTP, therefore be advised that your username and password (hash) will be transferred over-the-wire unencrypted. If you want to beef up the security, you may want to install a reverse HTTPS-enabled proxy in front of IRI API and accessing IRI API via this proxy.

Answer (score 1):

IOTA home made hash function Curl (different thing than curl library/utility) is the function used for authentication option.
To get it working take a look at http://lepsi-nez-zivot.blogspot.cz/2018/01/iota-iri-remote-authentication.html
JS code example shows how to compute the hash.